# Global validation of input in a C#/.NET environment?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm still quite new to C#, I know this is pretty easy in VBA (my "preferred" language).  I have a bunch of data input objects (text/numbers/dates) and I want to be able to validate that the input is logical for the field.  I don't want dates entered where text should be, I don't want integers entered where dates should be, etc...

I found this code that checks to see if a date entered is a valid date.  However, I'm confused as to where in a C#/.NET app this function should go, and I'm confused as to how to call the function from one of my pages.  Any help is appreciated.  At the moment I have it in Site.Master.cs, which sounded like the proper place to be.  I should state that I'd like to be able to put this validation in one place, as opposed to putting it on every form, because I've got 10 forms that have data entry controls on them.

```
static bool IsValidSqlDateTimeNative(string someval)
{
    bool valid = false;
    DateTime testDate = DateTime.MinValue;
    System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime sdt;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(someval, out testDate))
    {
        try
        {
            // take advantage of the native conversion
            sdt = new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime(testDate);
            valid = true;
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException ex)
        {
            // no need to do anything, this is the expected out of range error
        }
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, both Dave S and Magnus.  I had to kind of use a little from both of you, but more from Dave so I'm giving him the check.  I had to set both the class and the variable as static, which was missing from Dave's response but was present in Magnus'.  Thank you BOTH!

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. I've edited mine for correctness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you add a new class and have this as a static method so you can call it from anywhere in your application?

For example:

```
 public static class DateTimeHelpers
 {          
      static bool IsValidSqlDateTimeNative(string someval)
      {
           bool valid = false;
           DateTime testDate = DateTime.MinValue;
           System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime sdt;
           if (DateTime.TryParse(someval, out testDate))
           {
               try
               {
                   // take advantage of the native conversion
                   sdt = new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime(testDate);
                   valid = true;
               }
               catch (System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException ex)
               {
                   // no need to do anything, this is the expected out of range error
               }
           }
           return valid;
       }
 }
```

Then call from anywhere in the application like this:

```
 bool result = DateTimeHelpers.IsValidSqlDateTimeNative(mystring);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?  How would I go about doing that?  I hate to sound like a n00b, but I have to admit that when it comes to C# that's exactly what I am.  :o)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class Validation
{
    public static bool IsValidSqlDateTimeNative(string someval)
    {
        DateTime testDate;
        return DateTime.TryParse(someval, out testDate) && 
               testDate >= SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var isValidSqlDate = Validation.IsValidSqlDateTimeNative("1200-01-01");
```

Also worth mentioning is that you can use datatype [DateTime2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) in the database which has a  larger date range (same as the .net `DateTime` type) and a larger fractional precision.

Answer (score 0):

A big difference between creating web-pages in .NET versus most scripting languages is that everything is generally compiled together into one big (fat) binary. This is generally the equivalent of having a single `include.<lang>` that includes everything, and then include that into your page. What this means in practice, is that you in C#/.NET normally create classes that are .cs files (ie. not in pages/master-files), and you simply call the functions/classes defined in said files from your pages/masters-files.

Also, as of C#'s object-oriented structure, you can't just create functions in the global namespace (or any namespace for that matter), you have to create a class, and then have your function live inside said class.